# Integral of continuous function over a triangle

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, simple-functions

> Let $D\subset\mathbb{R^2}$ a triangle which has the corners $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$ and $g: \mathbb{R} -> \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Then
>
> $\int_Dg(x+y)dL^2(x,y)=\int_0^1tg(t)dt$
>
> where $L^2$ is the Lebesguemeasure in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

So my idea is, to split $g=g_+-g_-$ then it is enough to show the equality for $\phi_I$ with $I=[t_1,t_2]\subset[0,1]$ and $\phi$ being the characteristic function of I since $g$ is continuous.

So let $F(x,y)=x+y$ then $\phi_I(F(x,y))=\phi_{F^{-1}(I)}$. Furthermore, let $D_t$ be a triangle with corners$(0,0)  ,(t,0),(0,t). $ Then $\phi_{F^{-1}(I)}=D_{t_2}-D_{t_1}$

$\int_D\phi_I(F)dL^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_D*\phi_{F^{-1}(I)}dL^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_{F^{-1}(I)}dL^2=L^2(D_{t_2}-D_{t_1})=\frac{t_1^2}{2}-\frac{t_2^2}{2}=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}tdt=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}t*\phi_Idt$

Now letting $g_+=\sum\alpha _i\phi_{I_i}$ we get

$\int_Dg_+(F)dL^2=\sum\alpha _i\int_D\phi_{I_i}(F)dL^2=\sum\alpha _i\int_{I_i}t*\phi_{I_i}dt=\int_0^1tg_+(t)dt$

Doing this for $g_-$ then gives the equation.

This solution -if it is correct- is rather ugly in my opinion and I wonder if there's a better way to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter way. By changing variables and letting $(t,s)=(x+y,x-y)$, we have that the new domain of integration is the triangle of vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$, and
$$\int_Dg(x+y)dL^2(x,y)=\int_{t=0}^1\int_{s=-t}^t g(t) \frac{dtds}{2}=
\int_{t=0}^1g(t)\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_{s=-t}^t ds  \right) dt=\int_{t=0}^1tg(t)\,dt,$$
where the Jacobian determinant is $|\partial(t,s)/\partial(x,y)|=2$.

Comment: This is indeed alot nicer. Sadly We haven't learned the Jacobian determinant for transformations in measure theory yet. (I know how it works from physics classes, though. So your solution is satisfying for me)

Comment: May be you can avoid it by taking the rotation $(t,s)=(x+y,x-y)/\sqrt{2}$ which is area invariant.

Comment: That sounds promising, I'll look into that, thanks.